# bash command substitution with redirection: bad file descriptor

Tags: bash, io-redirection, command-substitution, dash

the following command works in dash but fails in bash with "Bad file descriptor".

```
$ dash -c 'out=$(echo "to fd3" >&3; echo "to stdout") 3>&1; echo "out: $out"'
to fd3
out: to stdout

$ bash -c 'out=$(echo "to fd3" >&3; echo "to stdout") 3>&1; echo "out: $out"'
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
out: to stdout
```

when i replace the command substition with a subshell then it seems to work in dash and bash.

```
$ dash -c '(echo "to fd3" >&3; echo "to stdout") 3>&1'
to fd3
to stdout

$ bash -c '(echo "to fd3" >&3; echo "to stdout") 3>&1'
to fd3
to stdout
```

---

versions:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

don't know how to get dash version. the man page on my system is dated January 19, 2003.

---

research:

i looked up how bash and dash executes a command. this is what i found.

for bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation

for dash: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html (section "Simple Commands")

as far as i understand both do expansions before redirections. command substitution is an expansion. so it makes sense that file descriptor 3 is not set up in the command substitution.

why does it work in dash? why does it not work in bash? is it a bug in dash? or bash? is it a valid construct at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether redirections are performed before or after assignment expansion is [unspecified by POSIX when there's no command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), so both are valid and you can't rely on either. So portably, you'd need:

```
{ out=$(echo "to fd3" >&3; echo "to stdout"); } 3>&1
```

AT&T `ksh` and the Bourne shell behave like `bash`; `zsh`, `pdksh`, `yash` behave like `dash` in this instance.

Comment: Why using `{  }` makes it more portable? Does it impose a precedence rule between redirection and assignment expansion (and if so which one) or is there something else to it? `{ }` won't spawn a subshell, right?

Comment: @TheQuark, it did spawn a subshell in the Bourne shell. Not in POSIX / modern shells. Here you're redirecting the command group, so there's not question that redirections within commands inside the command group could be done before.

Comment: Ah, the explanation is [lower here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04): *The shell has several programming constructs that are "compound commands", [...]. Each of these compound commands has a reserved word or control operator at the beginning, and a corresponding terminator reserved word or operator at the end. In addition, each can be followed by **redirections on the same line as the terminator**. Each redirection **shall apply to all the commands within the compound command that do not explicitly override that redirection.***

Comment: (Just as reference) The key sentence in the [unspecified by POSIX when there's no command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) link is: ***In the preceding list, the order of steps 3 and 4 may be reversed if no command name results from step 2 or if the command name matches the name of a special built-in utility**; see [Special Built-In Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).*